# How i can input keep value after submit, php?

Tags: php, html, reload

I am making account registeration page with php. My problem is taht, if somebody uses username which is already in use, page reloads and all inputs will empty.

I tried this:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" />
</br>
```

Comment: Use SESSION or more efficient way to use AJAX and jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is to send the check for a duplicate username via AJAX. Use JavaScript to send the request a second or two after the user is done typing.

If you don't want to use AJAX, store the field values in the session and spit them back out when the page reloads. This is your page:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>
```

Then, in the form submission code:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Your code could work if your form-handling code and you form markup are in the same PHP file, but you certainly aren't violating separation of concerns like that, are you? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the method of your form to POST, so you can't use `$_GET`, instead you have to use `$_POST`.

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']); ?>" />
</br>
```